# detecting a whitespace string

Tags: java, file, dom, whitespace

considering we have following strings and we are going to write them into a text file:

```
String a="        "
String b="  "
String c="java "
String d=" java"
String e="java"
```

but because `a and b` has no character , we have no interest to insert them into the file.
maybe here its easy to see them and ignore them, but what if there is a `DOM` tree and we get nodes text one by one and because of lots of white spaces in the page, there are lots of white space strings like `[#text:            ]` in the `DOM` .
what is the way to find out strings like  `a and b` as blanks and then ignoring them to right it into a text?

Comment: Why is [#text: ] whitespace ? Explain this DOM thing further ...

Comment: @PeterMmm in you use node.getNodevalue(); then if the node is whte space it will be like that but in different length like **[#text:    ]** but  here in stackoverflow it ignors white spaces so it doesnt show it corect;y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s.trim().length() == 0;
```

or

```
s.trim().isEmpty();
```

or

```
s.matches("\\s*");
```

or

```
StringUtils.isBlank(s);
```

(that one needs Jakarta Commons Lang). I personally go with the last one as it's `null`-safe to boot.

Comment: but it will remove the other nodes as well

Comment: @lonesome Explain, what other nodes?

Comment: i mean i want a node with no character in it being skipped, but if a string has character and white spaces like in the my qestion, if i use **s.trim().length() == 0** then will it be same for both string **a** **b** **c** and **d** of my question?

Comment: @lonesome No, it won't. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: because "java " has a blank after character a at the end, doesnt that be considered as a trim()?

Comment: `System.out.println("   java   ".trim().equals("java"));` -- try it. Or `System.out.println("   java   ".trim().isEmpty());` Don't be afraid to try stuff out for yourself. It's safe :)

Comment: ooh, it returned true, so that means using **s.trim().length() == 0** only catches "  blank " kind of strings?

Comment: im trying but you know, its a big prog and takes time to see the effects of ur answers :)

Comment: There are always ways to test stuff like that quickly. For example, you can hijack **any** class in your project for a quick test -- just add a `main` method and run it. Delete the method afterwards, and no harm done.

Comment: yup your exactly right about it! and i thought trim means the number of whitespaces deleted from string thats why i asked that question

Comment: There's always Javadoc for that.